# My touchpad doesn't stop dragging immediately when I lift my finger. Can I change that?

Tags: gnome, touchpad

I found references to `xinput list` and that showed me the ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad at id=12. Running

```
while true ; do xinput query-state 12 ; done
```

I noticed that button[1]=down remained down for the annoying 250ms, so something new in Ubuntu 20 is setting that - it didn't happen under 16.

I found the ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad documentation here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/input/devices/elantech.html

but I don't know how to find the parameters[0] values mentioned in that document.

My  /sys/bus/serio/drivers/psmouse/serio2/ has reg_07 to 22, so I tried setting register 22 but it didn't seem to affect anything.

Any ideas for where else to look?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do I always find things only moments after posting?

This fixed it for me:

```
synclient LockedDrags=0
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1089869)

Comment: @Pilot6 Hi. Thanks for responding. I thought it was clear from context that this was the solution. I've updated the answer to say so. If that's not what you meant, please be more explicit.

Comment: Sry, I misunderstood the answer.